# Pass a value to a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I am facing a problem, I will explain:
I set up a calendar on my website, when I click on an event to this calendar I open a popup until the hopefully it works correctly, I would like to change the content of my popup by inserting values my event.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                z=open('popup.html','','width=400,height=200,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,location=0,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no');
                z.document.getElementById('test').append(toto);
              },
```

Above me the code that opens my popup correctly I created a new file by "popup.html.

The last line does not work against ...

```
z.document.getElementById('test').append(toto);
```

I have an element with the id "test" in the HTML file of my popup. I also tried to generate the popum the fly from my script, I get this solution in a properly transmit information I want displayed in the popup io unfortunately I do not find a solution to the stylized popup window

```
w=open("",'popup','width=400,height=200,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes');  
w.document.write("<TITLE>"+document.forms[0].elements["titre"].value+"</TITLE>");
w.document.write("<BODY> Hello"+document.forms[0].elements["nom"].value+"<BR><BR>");
w.document.write("this popup work");
w.document.write("</BODY>");
w.document.close();
```

Do you have a solution to my / my problem?
Thank you in advance,
Good afternoon,
cordially

Comment: Do you really want a new window? Or do you only want a modal, like the [jQuery.UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/dialog/)?

Comment: Ui dialog would be perfect, I did not know what component
Can you tell me how to pass parameters to my component?
I have the jQuery library and its theme installed Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually you would prepare a `<div>`, e.g. `var z = $("#toto"); z.dialog({ autoOpen: false });` and use `z.dialog('open')` to open it. Note that this will remove `#toto` from its parent. If you don't wish this behavior try `var z = $("#toto").clone()` instead.

Comment: ok thank you, I try and I'll let you know

Comment: this code works thank you very much, last question is it possible to add CSS classes to my div and whether or should I add my styles?
`code var test = "<div class='test'>Titre:"+ calEvent.title + "</br>Titre: ToTO</div>"
      $(test).dialog({
        title    : "Détails de la réservation",
        width    : 500,
        height    : 300,

        })`
thank you

Comment: Just use `test.addClass('classname')` and prepare a CSS class called `.classname`. Also, your missing a "=" sign in your `div`: `"<div class='test'>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really want a new window? Or do you only want a modal, like the [jQuery.UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/docs/dialog/)?
In order to use the latter you usually prepare a `<div>`, e.g.

```
var myDialog = $("#toto"); 
myDialog.dialog({ autoOpen: false });
```

and use `myDialog.dialog('open')` to open it. Note that this will remove `#toto` from its parent. If you don't wish this behavior try `var myDialog = $("#toto").clone()`.

You can then style the new dialog with the [jQuery css methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/).